# How do I dynamically launch sub-jobs or sub-flows?

Tags: spring-batch

Step 1 of my batch job is to determine which databases/tables need to be processed.  For each of those databases or tables I want to launch a separate (ideally parallel) job or flow to handle that specific database/table.

Should I write something that dynamically launches separate instances of the same job with different jobParameters?  Would a [RepeatOperation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/repeat.html) be better?  I was looking at [split flows](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#split-flows) but it appears that you have to know the exact steps to split in each flow and I want to duplicate the flows dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a partitioned step and have each partition represents one of the database table to be processed.  From there, each partitioned step would launch the child job that contains the logic to process each table with the table as a job parameter.